# Vuejs - creating computed property based on Map reference

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am trying to create a computed property based on multiple ref objects, which updates relatively by user selection (selectedSourceGuids & SelectedTopic).

I have the following code, while it don't think that's a good practice!

What implementation would be a better solution to avoid foreach loop?

```js
class DataSerie {
  color: string
  name: string
  data: [number, number][]

  constructor(data: [number, number][], alias: string, name: string) {
    this.name = alias
    this.data = data
    this.name = name
    this.color = ''
  }
}

class Meassurements {
  sources = new Map<string, Source>()
}

class Source {
  data = new Map<string, [number, number][]>()
}

const data = ref(new Meassurements())
const selectedSourceGuids = ref<string[]>([])
const selectedTopic = ref('')

const selectedData = computed(() => {
  const result = [] as DataSerie[]
  data.value.sources.forEach((val, key) => {
    if(!selectedSourceGuids.value.includes(key)) return
    const data = val.data.get(selectedTopic.value)
    if(data)
    result.push(new DataSerie(data, key, key))
  });
  return result
})
```

Comment: It's ok. Since you're using a map, you'd need to convert it to an array to map-filter in less verbose manner. Neither classes nor a map are necessary here, would be simpler with plain objects and arrays.

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks for the points. Basically I used map to take advantages of helper methods, and also used class to add bit more functionality than the simple code I dropped above.